# JPA OneToMany Relationship with Distinct

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I have 3 tables and 3 subsequent entities, which are Companies which has a OneToMany with Users which has a OneToMany with Shirts.

So just to be clear each Company has many Users and each User has many Shirts.

Company has 2 columns CompanyId and CompanyName
Users has 3 columns UserId, Username and CompanyId (this is foreign key)
Shirts has has 4 columns ShirtId, ShirtColor, ShirtBrand and UserId (this is foreign key)

Currently I have a named query like this

```
@NamedQuery(name="Company.getCompanyById", query="SELECT c FROM Company c WHERE c.companyId = :companyId")
```

When I call this query and pass the companyId, I get back an object that contains the compnay, all the users for that company, and all the shirt for that user. In JSON it looks like this

```
{
    CompanyId:1,
    CompanyName:"ABC Inc",
    {Users:[{UserId:1,Usernmae:"James",
              Shirts:{[
                 {Color:"Blue", Brand:"GAP"},
                 {Color:"Blue", Brand:"Old Navy"}]
              }                 
     }]} 
}
```

Now if I wanted to have a similar query, but only return shirts that are DISTINCT by color to the specific user how could I do that?

So it would be like

```
{
    CompanyId:1,
    CompanyName:"ABC Inc",
    {Users:[{UserId:1,Usernmae:"James",
              Shirts:[Blue]                 
     }]} 
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please explain more what you mean by "shirts that are DISTINCT to the specific user". Preferably by example...

Comment: @BřetislavWajtr see edit